# Parameter without datatype in Mysql Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedures

Ok, so while writing a Stored Procedure in MYSQL i came across a problem where i had to write a procedure where i had to pass a parameter whose data type could depend upon the other parameter. I mean let us say that the first parameter is an a Boolean. If the value of Boolean variable is true, the other variable is of Character Datatype, other wise integer datatype.

The datatype of the second parameter will depend upon the value of the first in parameter! how can we decide the code at runtime?? sounds a bit unpractical and crazy, but is it really possible by some means??

Hope im not really sounding very foolish,
Thanks in advance!!!